# I need to create haskell function, which returns all possible binary trees, given a list of integers

Tags: haskell, tree, permutation

As the title says, I need this:

```
    getAllTrees :: [Int] -> [Tree Int]
    getAllTrees xs = undefined
```

where tree is

```
    data Tree x 
      = Null
      | Leaf x
      | Node (Tree x) x (Tree x)
```

I will appreciate any help, even the smallest clue :)
Thanks

Comment: Any element can be at the root.

Comment: It's not a homework, however I'm going to use this function as one of means to get my homework done :)

Comment: You realize the the number of possible trees grows very fast with the length of the list?

Comment: Do you need to preserve the element order? Are you allowed to assume that the input list doesn't contain duplicate elements, or are you perhaps allowed to include the same tree more than once in the output list? Have you any idea where to start? What have you managed to do yourself, and which bit have you trouble with?

Comment: Yes, I realize that augustss, I should mention that the trees are to consist of 5 vertices.

Comment: @user1166935: That seems rather arbitrary - what should you do if the list contains more than five elements?

Comment: The order doesn't matter and the list of elements is [1,2,3,4,5]. I'm looking to return list of all 42 trees from that function dave4420. I was working on something else in the meantime, so didn't do a thing about it. Although Peteris's answer helped me to imagine how it will work, I do know that I will need an additional function at each step of recursive call to exhaust all possible subtrees combinations - and that I don't know how to do...

Comment: Rampion, I need it to work with 5 element list only.

Comment: @user1166935: I hate to tell you this, but there's 120 binary trees of `[1..5]`.  Do you mean binary search trees?

Comment: @rampion Actually, I think it's 5040 binary trees of [1..5].

Comment: @augustss: quite right, I was only counting permutations, not accounting for split points.  my mistake.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I usually find it easiest to use the list monad for these kinds of problems. We can define `getAllTrees` by reasoning as follows:

The only tree of zero items is `Null`:

```
getAllTrees [] = return Null
```

There is also only one tree of one element, namely a `Leaf`:

```
getAllTrees [x] = return $ Leaf x
```

When we have more than one element, we can split the list in all possible ways to determine how we should branch, and then recursively generate the sub-trees from each list. Let's say we have a function `splits :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]` that returns all ways of splitting a list, for example:

```
> splits [1..3]
[([],[1,2,3]),([1],[2,3]),([1,2],[3]),([1,2,3],[])]
```

We can then define the final case of `getAllTrees` by using the list monad. This allows us to write code which sort of looks like like we're focusing on only one case, and the monad will give us all the combinations.

```
getAllTrees xs = do
  (left, x : right) <- splits xs
  Node <$> getAllTrees left <*> pure x <*> getAllTrees right
```

The first line splits the input list and takes the first item from the second part as the middle element. The case when the second part is empty doesn't match the pattern, so it gets discarded since that's how the list monad handles pattern match failures.

The second line uses applicative syntax to say that we want the result to be a list of nodes, made from all combinations of sub-trees from the `left` list, the fixed middle element `x`, and all sub-trees from the `right` list.

All that remains then is to implement `splits`. Looking at the example above, it's easy to see that we can just take the `inits` and `tails` of the list and `zip` them together:

```
splits xs = zip (inits xs) (tails xs)
```

Time for a quick sanity check in the interpreter:

```
> mapM_ print $ getAllTrees [1..3]
Node Null 1 (Node Null 2 (Leaf 3))
Node Null 1 (Node (Leaf 2) 3 Null)
Node (Leaf 1) 2 (Leaf 3)
Node (Node Null 1 (Leaf 2)) 3 Null
Node (Node (Leaf 1) 2 Null) 3 Null
> length $ getAllTrees [1..5]
42
```

Looks like we're done! Some key lessons:

- Try to think about the small cases first, and build up from there.
- The list monad is useful for code that needs to generate all combinations of things.
- You don't have to do everything at once. Dealing with the list splitting separately made the code much simpler than it would have been otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is more that I was counting on :)

Comment: One more thing bro: <*>, <$> and 'pure' are not in scope. What do I need to import?

Comment: @user1166935: They're found in `Control.Applicative`. Operators can be difficult to Google, but [Hoogle finds them easily](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3C%2A%3E).

Comment: That only returns the trees where the nodes are in the same order as in the list.  That's not what the question asked for (even if perhaps that's what was wanted).

Comment: @augustss: Yes, I inferred that from the expected number of trees mentioned in the comments, though the full list can be obtained by simply doing `permutations xs >>= getAllTrees`.